# SQL Server check constraint logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've got a table that has such kind of structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Mine
(
    ProductID INT
    , CountryID INT
    , ApplicationID INT
);
```

Let's assume it has data as follows:

```
ProductID   CountryID   ApplicationID
1           2           -1
1           3           -1
1           3            2
```

I'd like to enforce such logic that there's no other `ProductID`/`CountryID` combination in **entire table** if it exists with `ApplicationID = -1`. In My example 2nd and 3rd row wouldn't pass this.

I could create a custom function to validate that and make a `CHECK` constraint out of it. Is there perhaps a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I've answered but now I'm not so sure it's valid. Are you saying you only want a single row to exists where `ApplicationID` is -1?

Comment: @DavidG Correct, there can be more than one row of `ProductID`/`CountryID` combination with other ApplicationIDs other than -1.

Comment: I think my edit does this now.

Comment: @DavidG - I think you are misreading and think that you had it right the first time (and I and also the post there after). The combination is unique only when `ApplicationID = -1` but there can be more than one `ApplicationID = -1` in the table provided the `ProductID/CountryID` are different.

Comment: @Igor No, see the comment on Dan's answer. I'm understanding this less and less...

Comment: I'll update question to include more examples of what I'd expect, sorry for all the fuss.

Comment: @DavidG - Ah, I think I understand. So `ProductID/CountryID` is only unique as soon as there also exists a `ProductID/CountryID` record where `ApplicationID = -1`, at that point there should only be a single `ProductID/CountryID` record for that combination. Is that correct?

Comment: @Igor That's correct.

Comment: Then the only option you have is a before update/insert trigger, an index or check constraint cant handle this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking trigger/check too. Alternatively, a rethink of the design may be in order.

Comment: There's no before triggers in SQL Server, unfortunately, you can try to simulate those. I guess only option is a function in CHECK constraint then.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, SQL Server had `INSTEAD OF` triggers, which can provide functionality similar to before triggers.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'll check that, perhaps It's possible to emulate before trigger using this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split your task. First, assign unique constraint (this can be table Key):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_UQ ON Mine(ProductId, CountryId, ApplicationId)
```

This is for trivial validations and to improve trigger query.

Second, your check requires many records involved (no CHECK constraint possible). This is task for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trMine
ON Mine FOR INSERT,UPDATE
IF (EXISTS(
        SELECT Mark FROM
        (
            SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN M.ApplicationId=-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*(COUNT(*)-1) Mark
            FROM Mine M
            JOIN inserted I ON M.ProductId=I.ProductId AND M.CountryId=I.CountryId
            GROUP BY M.ProductId,M.CountryId
        ) Q
        WHERE Mark != 0
    )) THROW 50000, 'Validation error', 1
```

When there are 2 or more records (COUNT(*)-1>0) and there is any record with ApplicationId=-1, Mark evaluates to something != 0. This is your violation rule.

Comment: This seems right, not elegant as I would've wished, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a Unique [Filtered Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc280372.aspx):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_UniqueNegativeApp ON Mine(ProductID, CountryID) WHERE ApplicationID = -1
```